# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Tags: python

I'm new to python environments and I'm currently working on a ml project. While reading a CSV file using readlines function I'm getting "tuple has no attribute readlines". Please someone help me.....

my code is

```
data_file=(r"C:\Users\Sury teja\temp\mnist_train.csv","r")
print(data_file.readlines())
```

error is

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

Comment: You missed `open`.

Comment: Please don't edit your post to "fix" the code: that renders the existing answers nonsensical, and the question inconsistent (since the error you show no longer occurs). I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `open`:

```
data_file = open(r"C:\Users\Sury teja\temp\mnist_train.csv", "r")
print(data_file.readlines())
```

In the code you wrote, `data_file` is just a tuple, which looks like this:

```
('C:\\Users\\Sury teja\\temp\\mnist_train.csv', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is caused by the parenthesis around two arguments:

`(r"C:\Users\Sury teja\temp\mnist_train.csv","r")`

This is caused by the fact that parenthesis are serving more than one purpose in Python: they are used for calling - for example - functions, like in this example, but also for initializing immutable data structures called tuples.

By omitting the function name (`open`) you have initialized a tuple instead of calling the `open` function. And tuple, like your error suggests, has no attribute `readlines`.

Comment: `()` aren't required for tuples. Try `a = 1, 2`

Comment: @roganjosh true, but a tuple was initialized in this case

Comment: Sure. But "... but also for initializing immutable data structures called tuples." isn't correct

Comment: I disagree. Parenthesis _can_ be used and _are_ used for initializing tuples. The fact that they can be initialized in other ways, like with `tuple()` or `1, 2` doesn't make previous sentence false.

Comment: It does in the context of the problem that the OP is facing. I'll agree that you can initialise an empty tuple with `()`, but that's pretty much useless, and they'd have a tuple without parentheses here at all

Comment: true, but I have described what actually occurred and caused the `AttributeError`.

Comment: I'm dropping it anyway; I haven't voted on the answer. But, from a lot (too much) of time on SO, there is a misconception that parentheses are required for tuples, when really, it's the comma. Without `open`, the parentheses are doing nothing here but your answer suggests they _do_ do something